# The for loop in R returns only the last iteration

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R and also pretty new to programming. So my question could be pretty silly, but any help would be appreciated.

The csv files containing the inputs looks like this:

```
Width   Depth   WL1 WL2 V1   V2
0       0       50  52  0    0
0       95      50  52  0.4  0.41
100     100     50  52  0.5  0.5
200     130     50  52  0.7  0.73
300     125     50  52  0.46 0.48
400     115     50  52  0.25 0.28
500     95      50  52  0.24 0.24
600     75      50  52  0.4  0.41
700     80      50  52  0.32 0.3
800     80      50  52  0.09 0.1
900     70      50  52  0    0
1000    60      50  52  0   0
1100    50      50  52  0   0
1200    40      50  52  0   0
1300    30      50  52  0   0
1400    30      50  52  0   0
1500    15      50  52  0   0
1600    5       50  52      
1600    0       50  52
```

So I am reading inputs from a .csv file to do the calculations for river discharge (total_flow). The values for water level and velocity change with time and I have stored in consecutive columns in the csv file. The code is calculating the discharge for the last iteration accurately. How to I alter my code to get the discharge for all the iteration? My code is shown below:

```
field_data <- read.csv("Information_VRH-11-09-14.csv", header = TRUE)
# field_data
width <- field_data[[1]]
width
# length(width)
actual_depth <- field_data[[2]]
actual_depth
# length(actual_depth)
for (i in 3:4)
{
    water_level <- field_data[[i]]
}

# Calculations for depth data
ref_depth <- actual_depth[2:18]
ref_depth
water_level <- water_level[2:18]
water_level
depth_data <- ref_depth - water_level
depth_data
for (i in 1:length(depth_data))
{
    if (depth_data[i] < 0) 
        depth_data[i] <- 0
}
depth_data
dL <- depth_data[1:16]
dR <- depth_data[2:17]

# Submerged width of the trapezoids
xdata <- width[2:18]
xdata
length(xdata)
n <- length(xdata)
xL <- xdata[1:16]
xR <- xdata[2:17]

# Velocity
for (i in 5:6)
{
    velocity <- field_data[[i]]
    vdata <- velocity[2:(length(xdata))]
}
vdata

# Calculation of discharge and area of trapezoids
Area <- (((xR - xL) * (dR + dL))/2)/10000
Area
flow <- Area * vdata
flow
total_flow <- sum(flow)
total_flow
```

Comment: Two comments: Anytime you find yourself using `for` loops in R for vector operations you should pause and question what you are doing, and if you must use `for` loops, please use brackets so it is clear which code comprises the body of the loop.

Comment: ...and add some toy data. We don't know what is in `Information_VRH-11-09-14.csv`

Comment: This can't have run in R. You need `{` and `}` surrounding the body of statements in a for loop. And please us indentation so that the body of a for loop (or any nested block of statements) stands out clearly.